# Django 4.0 - Saving Multiple Options using MultipleChoiceField

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to save Multiple Choice Fields in an array inside my database

I have no idea how to do this, I have a working solution by using the standard ChoiceField but it only saves one option at the moment

I want my values inside the database to show as for example "Beavers, Cubs" or "Scouts, Cubs"

How can I change my current code to do this?

(This is only my 2nd question so any constructive criticism will be appreciated)

models.py

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # A full User model with admin-compliant permissions that uses a full-length email field as the username
    # Email and password are required but all other fields are optional
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), max_length=254, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    section = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True,
        help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'))
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'))
    is_executive = models.BooleanField(_('executive status'), default=False, 
        help_text=_('Designates that this user is part of the executive committee.'))
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(_('superuser status'), default=False, 
        help_text=_('Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.'))
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%s/" % urlencode(self.email)

    def get_full_name(self):
        # Returns the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        # Returns the short name (first name) for the user
        return self.first_name
```

views.py

```py
def register(request):
    articles = Article.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-date_posted')[:2]
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.username = request.POST.get('username')
            user.section = request.POST.get('section')
            user.second_section = request.POST.get('second_section')
            user.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    
    context = {
        'title': 'Register',
        'articles': articles,
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', context)
```

forms.py

```py
SECTION = [
    ('Beavers', 'Beavers'),
    ('Cubs', 'Cubs'),
    ('Scouts', 'Scouts'),
]

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    section = forms.ChoiceField(label='Childs Section', choices=SECTION, widget=forms.RadioSelect, 
        help_text='Please select the section that your child currently attends.')
    """
    section = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label='Childs Section', choices=SECTION, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, 
        help_text='Please select the section(s) that your child currently attends.')
    """
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2', 'section']
```

Comment: Which field shall store that? and where is the form?

Comment: @MohamedElKalioby it is `section = models.CharField(max_length=30)` and the form to select the options gets rendered in the Register form (which is the bottom code block)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the views.py change the following line

```
user.section = request.POST.get('section')
```

to

```
user.section = ‘,’.join(request.POST.getlist('section'))
```

Or change ‘section’ to be a JSONField and list to it.

Comment: This gives me an 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'get_list' error

Comment: It should be getlist(), check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Its always a good practice to have your choice filed in your backend before adding it to your forms.py like so :

```
SECTION = (('BC', 'Beaver Cubs',),('SC', 'Scout Cubs',))

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # A full User model with admin-compliant permissions that uses a full-length email field as the username
    # Email and password are required but all other fields are optional
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), max_length=254, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    # Here we make the selection of our section in choice filed 
    section = models.CharField(choices=SECTION, max_length=10)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True,
        help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'))
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'))
    is_executive = models.BooleanField(_('executive status'), default=False, 
        help_text=_('Designates that this user is part of the executive committee.'))
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(_('superuser status'), default=False, 
        help_text=_('Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.'))
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)
   
     
    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%s/" % urlencode(self.email)

    def get_full_name(self):
        # Returns the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        # Returns the short name (first name) for the user
        return self.first_name
```

then we add the field to our form like so :

```
lass UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 
        'password2', 'section']
         widgets = {
            'section': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'custom-select md-form'}),
        }

#  This is as clean and good practice
```

Comment: I'll try this out, thanks

Comment: Abu, this just renders a blank text field

Comment: You have to apply migrations first

Comment: After that you sync the migration  into your database  by manage.py  migrate!

Comment: Oh okay, I forgot to do that :/

Comment: Migrated, now I get a drop-down menu where it only lets me select one option

Comment: Do want to be able to select both options ? in the section field ?

Comment: Yes I do, I want it so users can have access to multiple sections, therefore granting then access to multiple blogs at one time